# Umm... where's the favicon?

Tags: bug, design

I know is there, when I inspect the area were it should be is there, yet I CANNOT SEE IT!! D:<

[image]

Can the background contrast be dial up?

Comment: Have you tried moving your head slightly closer to the screen?

Comment: @Richard I shouldn't be so near to the screen... it damage my eyes, you know ;)

Comment: Have you tried pressing the contrast button on your monitor?

Comment: Ah yes, I can see the problem from the screenshot. It is a clear case of having your monitor's contrast too low. Try increasing it, and then post the (fixed) screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

With the [redesign](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7581/a-design-update-is-coming) rolling out [soon](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7581/a-design-update-is-coming#comment20670_7581), it'll be fixed:

[image]

Comment: You've been posting lots of nice pictures of what the redesign will look like! Are you one of the SE devs? I thought all the devs had diamonds on every site??

Comment: @rand 1. Sure! 2. No xD 3. No (as for me, actually I haven't got diamonds anywhere).

Comment: If you're not one of the devs, how are you getting all these pictures? Can anybody see the redesigned site if they look in the right place?

Comment: @rand It's obviously a secret. What have you tried?

Comment: I've clicked on lots of the links in your answers, and tried silly things like http://new.meta.scifi.stackexchange.com. It must be quite a secret! :-D